# Prevent an Object from destroying prematurely

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, destructor

Here's the (relevant) code for my `pro::surface` class:

```
/** Wraps up SDL_Surface* **/
class surface
{
    SDL_Surface* _surf;
public:
    /** Constructor.
     ** @param surf an SDL_Surface pointer.
     **/
    surface(SDL_Surface*);

    /** Overloaded = operator. **/
    void operator = (SDL_Surface*);

    /** calls SDL_FreeSurface(). **/
    void free();

    /** destructor. Also free()s the internal SDL_Surface. **/
    virtual ~surface();
}
```

Now the problem is that in my `main` function, the object destroys itself (and hence calls the destructor which dangerously `free()`s the SDL Video Surface!) before the real rendering begins.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ...
    // declared here
    pro::surface screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(320,240,16,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);

    // event-handling done here, but the Video Surface is already freed!
    while(!done) { ... }  // note that "screen" is not used in this loop.

    // hence, runtime error here. SDL_Quit() tries to free() the Video Surface again.
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is, is there any way to stop the `pro::surface` instance from destroying itself before the program ends? Doing memory management manually works though:

```
/* this works, since I control the destruction of the object */
pro::surface* screen = new pro::surface( SDL_SetVideoMode(..) ); 

/* it destroys itself only when **I** tell it to! Muhahaha! */
delete screen;

/* ^ but this solution uses pointer (ewww! I hate pointers) */
```

But isn't there a better way, without resorting to pointers? Perhaps some way to tell the stack to not delete my object just yet?

Comment: Is `pro::surface` "yours"?  I don't know about SDL, is it possible to hold the `SDL_Surface` in a shared pointer instead of a raw pointer?  Or at least something with shared pointer semantics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You violated the Rule of Three, bitch.

```
pro::surface screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(320,240,16,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
```

Is equal to

```
pro::surface screen = pro::surface(SDL_SetVideoMode(320,240,16,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF));
```

Now double free, because you violated the Rule of Three. So give your class a proper copy constructor/assignment operator, or disallow them and explicitly construct it properly.

Edit: This also explains why your pointer version works fine- because you don't invoke a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the screen in a special wrapper, that pairs `SDL_SetVideoMode` with `SDL_Quit` instead of `SDL_FreeSurface`.

```
pro::screen screen(320, 240, 16, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
// ...
```

And fix your copy ctor, *obviously*.